# Creating a Dynamic Table to Display Monthly Performance in Excel for 2023

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: The final table]
[image: The data in excel file]

I'm working on a project where I need to create a dynamic table in Excel to showcase the monthly performance for the year 2023. Each month should have its own column, and the table should automatically update as new data is added.

I've tried using formulas like INDEX, MATCH, and OFFSET, but I'm having trouble setting up the table to dynamically adjust to the changing data. Can someone guide me on the most effective way to achieve this? Are there any specific functions or techniques I should be using?

Any help or example formulas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What formula did you try? What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to format the input data as a table  should make it easy to update. Use a countifs formula and the MONTH and EOMONTH fucntions for your dates,

Assuming that the most recent data in the table is always the reporting month

```
reporting month
    =COUNTIFS(Table1[Discipline],"CVL",Table1[status],"issued", Table1[Inspection date],">="&DATE(YEAR(MAX(Table1[Inspection date])),MONTH(MAX(Table1[Inspection date])),1),Table1[Inspection date],"<="&EOMONTH(MAX(Table1[Inspection date]),0))
```

Previous month

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Discipline], "CVL", Table1[Status], "issued", Table1[Inspection date], ">=" & EOMONTH(MAX(Table1[Inspection date]), -1)+1, Table1[Inspection date], "<=" & EOMONTH(MAX(Table1[Inspection date]), -1))
```